# Maven build configuration Team city - Pass variable to feature file

Tags: maven, cucumber, teamcity

I have a cucumber feature file scenario for performing smoke test and a track server which should be passed dynamically , below https://tk2.dev.summitenergy.com should be passed as a parameter variable( not hardcoded)

Scenario: RA Login functionality
Given Open Firefox and start "https://tk2.dev.summitenergy.com"
When I enter "atesting" and "Testing@2"
    Then user should be login successfully

for that i have given "MAVEN_OPTS="-Dprop=%teamcity.project.id%" mvn surefire:test" in the **Additional command line parameters** feild while build configuration , I am not sure if it is the correct way to do

Can you please suggest me the correct way

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

As cucumber in maven is executed as JUnit test, please try to set following value in **Additional Maven command line parameters**

```
-DargLine="-Dprop=%teamcity.project.id%"
```

Note, that you do not need to put `MAVEN_OPTS` into field's value
Also, **Goals** are separate field, too. That is where `test` goal should be specified